Did Arab Christians use the word "Allah" before Islam?
Did arabic Christians and Jews use the word Allah to refer to god before Islam came about? Are there any texts predating Islam that prove this

Who affirms that it is true? You should include this information in the question, as basic research, as well as a bit more detail about this claim, to know what the old texts are expected to prove (or not).

See similar question, asked two hours later: christianity - Did others use the word "Allah" before islam - Islam Stack Exchange.

The common proto-language for both Arabic and Hebrew (proto-Central Semetic) had the word "El" which meant both a god, and the top/father God in their pantheon. Both Arabic and Hebrew are descended from this language.

One could argue the Jews later fixed the ambiguity by getting rid of the concept of any other gods, while the Arabs did so by creating a second word. (Probably just tacking the definite article on the front of it).
The word for "(a) god" in Arabic is Ilah. The word for "The" in Arabic (aka: the definite article) is "Al". So if one wanted to say "the God" with just that bit of the Arabic language (not using the word used in the Koran), it would have come out "Al-ilah". The feminine form ("the goddess") was "Al-ilahat"
Despite how similar "Al-ilah" looks (and likely sounded) to "Allah", the theory that the former is just a shortened version of the latter is quite controversial (as a lot of the other answers go into). Fortunately, that wasn't the question.

Why is it controversial?

One crucial question is which came first - was El originally just the word for 'god' and then was reduced to the chief god of these pantheons, or was it the chief god first, and then became a generic term for a god. Personally I find this to be where scholars sort of stop with an uncomfortable silence - for many it's preferable to imagine that it all began with complex pantheons (with no actual word for 'a god') and then was reduced to one god, rather than the inverse.

@Stevecanhelp There are categories in between monotheism and polytheism where it gets a little blurry too.  The early gnostic texts talk of "Aeons" as if they were divine emanations or reflections of the one true God, yet were also considered distinct in their own way.  They were certainly described to be god-like, although fell short of being considered a god in the traditional sense. This may be where the concept of archangels in modern Christianity derived from.

In fact, many scholars argue rather a lot of the Bible seems to have been written at a point when Jews did not deny the the existence of other gods, but insisted that they as a people weren't to be worshiping any other (hence the phrase "Jealous God" in Exodus, and mention of the god Leviathan in Genesis)

@T.E.D. - absolutely, I think you'd get broad agreement on that, there's a strong 'YHWH against the other gods" vibe across the OT, and usually it's more power/presence that's questioned rather than existence. But the idea that the Tanakh treats El as the top of a pantheon (especially above/distinct from YHWH as some claim) always felt more like a self-fulfilling prophecy than something that's clearly evidenced from the text anywhere.

Isn't the only answer that questions this etymology in detail just some anti-Muslim "Allah is actually a pagan moon god and not Abrahamic at all" diatribe? Is there actually something of value in its etymological assertions?

@Obie2.0 there's no unbiased an well sourced arguments there , they try to confirm true etymology to their views , so the best thing would be to ask Muslim or Jewish scholars about it

"Despite how similar "Al-ilah" looks (and likely sounded) to "Allah", the theory that the former is just a shortened version of the latter is quite controversial (as a lot of the other answers go into). Fortunately, that wasn't the question."                         As far as I know this is the majority opinion among scholars of the Arabic language , why do u think it's controversial ?  @T.E.D.

Did Arab Christians use the word "Allah" before Islam?
There is some historical evidence to indicate that Arab Christians did employ the word ”Alláh” before the coming of Islam.
It seems Arab Christians did employ Allah as referring to their Christian God.

First, some historical background. There were Arab Christians before the emergence of Islam that used Allah to refer to the Christian God. These were Arab tribes such as the Lakhmids, the Banu Taghlib, and the Ghassanids who lived on the borders of the Byzantine and Sassanian empires. In fact, one of the oldest sources of written Arabic is a monastery inscription written by Hind, mother of the Lakhmid king, Amr, which reads “This church was built by Hind, mother of King Amr and servant of Christ… May the God for whom she built this church forgiver her sins and have mercy on her son.” Arabic Christians have continued throughout history to use the name Allah to refer to the God of the Bible to the present day. The name Allah is linguistically related to the Aramaic name for God, Alaha, and more importantly, to the Hebrew name, El. So in terms of history and etymology, Allah has a strong case. It has been conveying the meaning of the God of Bible’s identity for at least 1,500 years among Arabic-speaking Christians. Its sister languages have been similarly using its cognates for even longer than that. - Can the Name of Allah Be Used for the Christian God?

Here follows some basic knowledge about the etymology of the word Allah:

Allah is the common Arabic word for God. In the English language, the word generally refers to God in Islam. The word is thought to be derived by contraction from al-ilāh, which means "the god", and is linguistically related to the Aramaic words Elah and Syriac ܐܲܠܵܗܵܐ (ʼAlāhā) and the Hebrew word El (Elohim) for God.
The word Allah has been used by Arabic people of different religions since pre-Islamic times.[9] The pre-Islamic Arabs worshipped a supreme deity whom they called Allah, alongside other lesser deities.[10] Muhammad used the word Allah to indicate the Islamic conception of God. Allah has been used as a term for God by Muslims (both Arab and non-Arab), Judaeo-Arabic-speaking Jews, and Arab Christians[11] after the terms "al-ilāh" and "Allah" were used interchangeably in Classical Arabic by the majority of Arabs who had become Muslims. It is also often, albeit not exclusively, used in this way by Bábists, Baháʼís, Mandaeans, Indonesian and Maltese Christians, and Sephardi Jews, as well as by the Gagauz people. Similar usage by Christians and Sikhs in Peninsular Malaysia has recently led to political and legal controversies.
The use of Allah as the name of a deity appears as early as the first century. An inscription using the Ancient South Arabian script in Old Arabic from Qaryat al-Fāw reads, "to Kahl and lh and ʿAththar (b-khl w-lh w-ʿṯr)".


Just went to my first syro-malabar Mass (Quarbana) last week at the Eucharistic Congress and glad you answered this way. I noticed the word Alaha in the liturgy and figured it referred to God

@PeterTurner Awesome. We have a Syro-Malabar Mass at our parish each month.

Peter Turner, sorry to partially disagree with you. The word used in Syro Malabar liturgy is Aalaha which has a distinct pronounciation vis- a-vis the word Allah used by Muslims. Both, of course means God. Being a Syrian Christians living among a number of Muslim brethren , I can easily make out the difference  .

To illustrate, the ' ll ' in 'Allah' is pronounced something like the ' ll' in wall with a strong accent.  On the other hand the ' l ' in Aalaha sounds like that in ' limit' .

Probably yes. The Arabic word Allah means "The God" (al + ilah). The Arabic word Ilah just means "God". Today Arabic Christians say Allah and even in Arabic Bibles you find the name Allah for God.
In the Aramaic parts of the Bible there is the word Elah, which means God. It is almost identical with the word Allah. They have the same letters, but Allah has one Lam more.

One lam more and starts with an E not an A? Are these the only differences?

Allah = Alif - Lam - Lam - Ha. Elah = Alif - Lam - Ha.

Oh sorry , why would it start with an E if the first letter was alif?

@Tahir: Alif is a consonant (a glottal stop); the vowel after it can vary.

@Jlem can you answer this please https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/23871/15873

This answer supplements @T.E.D's and @KenGraham's answers by describing the predominant translation policy by the Indonesian Bible Society (see Bible translations into Indonesian).  The translation policy is defended here by quoting from a 2001 article Translating the Names of God: recent experience from Indonesia and Malaysia by Daud Soesilo (UBS Regional Translations Coordinator for the Indo-Pacific Region) published in The Bible Translator Practical Papers Vol. 52 No. 4 (October 2001).  Quote from the paper:

There are five reasons why it is legitimate to use Allah among Christians.  They are as follows:

The loan word Allah is the Arabic equivalent of the Hebrew names of God El, Elohim, Eloah in the Hebrew Old Testament.
Arab Christians from before the dawn of Islam have been praying to Allah, and  Allah  was used by Christian theologians writing in Arabic. So the Christian usage of Allah is actually older than Islam.
Allah  is the word used for “God” in all Arabic versions of the Bible from the old Arabic Bible all the way to the modern Arabic Bible  (Today’s Arabic Version).
Christians in countries like Algeria, Egypt, Iraq, Jordan, Lebanon, Indonesia, Malaysia, Brunei, and other places in Asia and Africa where the languages are in contact with Arabic, have almost all been using the word Allah as the Creator God and the God and Father of the Lord Jesus Christ.
...


I use Indonesia as example because the country has the largest Muslim population but also has a significant Christian minority sharing a common language Bahasa Indonesia where the word "Allah" has been used to refer to the non-sectarian monotheistic "God" for decades since their 1945 Independence (from the Dutch), the time when Bahasa Indonesia became their national language.
In summary, this is their translation policy:

In the OT they transliterate ’ĕ·lō·hîm ("God" in English) as "Allah".  Example: Gen 1:14:


In the OT they transliterate Yah-weh ’ĕ·lō·hîm ("The LORD God") as "TUHAN Allah", matching the capitalizing convention in English where the "LORD" / "TUHAN" is considered a proper name.  Example: Gen 2:8:


In the NT they transliterate Theos ("God") as "Allah" matching the English translation convention.  Example: John 3:16:


In the NT they transliterate Kyriou Iēsou Christou ("Lord Jesus Christ") as "Tuhan Yesus Kristus", again, matching the English translation convention Kyriou -> Lord as well as the ancient Greek translator using Kyriou to transliterate the OT Hebrew Yah-weh. Example: Phil 4:23:


1 Cor 8:5-6 is interesting because we have both singular and plural forms for God and Lord in the same sentence.  But it's easy to see that again, theoi ("gods") is translated "banyak 'allah'" and kyrioi ("lords") is translated "banyak 'tuhan'" ("banyak" is an Indonesian pluralizing word, lit. means "many", corresponding to the Greek polloi).
Greek (see Interlinear 1 Cor 8:5, 1 Cor 8:6):

kai gar eiper eisin legomenaoi theoi eite en ouranō eite epi  gēs hōsper eisin theoi polloi kai kyrioi polloi all' hēmin heis Theos ho Patēr ex hou ta panta kai hēmeis eis auton kai heis Kyrios Iēsous Christos di' hou ta panta kai hēmeis di’ autou

English (CSB):

5 For even if there are so-called gods, whether in heaven or on earth—as there are many “gods” and many “lords”— 6 yet for us there is one God, the Father. All things are from him, and we exist for him. And there is one Lord, Jesus Christ. All things are through him, and we exist through him.

Indonesian:



(Screenshots are from the pdf of Indonesian Bible Society's widely used 1974 translation, pdf published on the Indonesian Ministry of Religion government website.  I purposely chose the pdf format to preserve the typographical convention which may be corrupted in an online / electronic version.)
CONCLUSION: It is uncontroversial for Indonesian Christians to use "Allah" as "God" (generic term for the monotheistic God), "TUHAN" as "LORD" (proper name for the Israelite's God), and in the New Testament  "Tuhan" as "Lord" as in "the Lord Jesus" ("Tuhan Yesus").  And this Indonesian practice (starting in the 20th century) follows the naming convention used by Christian theologians writing in Arabic since before the dawn of Islam.

Did Arab Christians Use the Word "Allah" before Islam?It is a known fact that the word, Allah was in use long before Mohammed was born---and before Islam became a religion. Mohammed's father's name was even Abd Allah (slave of Allah), indicating usage long before Islam.
Ancient "Allah""Allah" was by some historians considered to be the patron deity of the Quraysh tribe of Arabians, of which Mohammed's family was a part. It was one of the 360 gods worshipped in the Ka'aba in Mecca, although considered by some worshippers to be the Creator god over the other gods. When Mohammed destroyed the other "idol" gods, he kept "Allah" (the patron god of his clan) as the only one to be worshipped. [Christian Julien Robin (2012) Arabia and Ethiopia in The Oxford Handbook of Late Antiquity, pp 304-305; Anthony S. Mercatante (2004) Allah, Facts on File Encyclopedia of World Mythology and Legend  p. 53]
Christian usage of the NameAccording to info gleaned from Wikipedia's resources we are told:

Regional variants of the word Allah occur in both pagan and Christian pre-Islamic inscriptions.[9,28] According to Marshall Hodgson, it seems that in the pre-Islamic times, some Arab Christians made pilgrimage to the Kaaba, a pagan temple at that time, honoring Allah there as God the Creator.[29]


The Syriac word ('Elaha) can be found in the reports and the lists of Christian martyrs in South Arabia, as reported by antique Syriac documents of the names of those martyrs from the era of the Himyarite and Aksumite kingdoms. [30,31,32]


In an inscription of Christin martyrion dated back to 512, references to al-ilah can be found in both Arabic and Aramaic. The inscription starts with the statement, By the help of al-ilah. [33,34,35]


Irfan Shahid, quoting the 10th century encyclopedic collection Kitab al-Aghani notes that pre-Islamic Arab Christians have been reported to have raised the battle cry Ya La Ibad Allah (O slaves of Allah) to invoke each other into battle. According to Shahid, on the authority of 10th century Muslim scholar, Al-Marzubani, "Allah" was also mentioned in pre-Islamic poems by some Ghassabid and Tanukhid poets in Syria and Northern Arabia. [40,41,42]

[The specific References in this Wikipedia article are many and lengthy, so they are not spelled out here. But they can be easily found on that web site: https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Allah]
Christians, Jews, and Arabian tribes, all mingled together in the Mideast societies (first through sixth centuries), so it was natural for each to borrow verbiage from each other, as well as adopt customs. That the word "Allah" (al-ilah) should be found in all these societies is not unexpected.
BUT the use of this word would not necessarily have the same connotation in each of these societies. The Jews would acknowledge only one God; the Arabs would consider Allah to be the chief god (creator, even) over many gods. And the Christians would acknowledge Him to be the One God who was incarnated in Jesus Christ.
Islam's AllahMohammed's usage would take on a whole new meaning...with it as the basis of a new religion. And herein lies the friction among Christian believers, Bible translators, and societies governed by Islamic politicians (Ayatollahs, Imams, Caliphs, etc.).
The ancient Christians---and modern Christian believers who live in Muslim countries---would realize that every word has both a denotative and a connotative meaning. (A generic meaning and a specific or proper meaning.)
Whereas the ancient word "al-ilah" (the god), or the contraction, "Allah", would often just be a generic word for "god" (denotative), the Christians---ancient and modern---would have no qualms using it when referring to the Creator God of the universe generally. And it is used as such in modern translations of the Bible.
Muhammad's "Allah"But the new definition Muhammad gave to it (connotative) made it refer to something that is totally unacceptable to believing Christians.  It is declared that God is one (anti-trinitarian)...Allah has no sons (anti-Christ)...and Muhammad is His (final) prophet (anti-biblical canon). Daniel Janosik of Columbia International University explained:

But wait a minute, some would say. What about the Arabic Christians [ancient and modern] who call the God of the Bible "Allah"? Doesn't this illustrate the fact that Allah and Yahweh are referring to the same God? Actually, when the Arabic Christians refer to "Allah" in their translations of the Bible, they believe that "Allah"" is the father of Jesus and they believe that "Allah" is triune. Therefore, the Allah of the Arabic Christians cannot be the same Allah of the Muslims!
This semantic [shibbileth] strangulation can be cleared up if we remember that words have both a denotative and a connotative meaning. Denotative refers to a dictionary, so it would be correct to say that Yahweh and Allah both refer to the concept of God, especially for their respective language groups.


However, the connotation is determined by what a person  conceives about the object of that word. For example, an Arab Christian may still use the word Allah" to denote God, but his understanding of that term would be starkly different from a Muslim, for the would recognize that Jesus Christ is God (Allah) whereas the Muslim would never consider that connotation...


After comparing the Allah of the Qur'an and the [Allah] Yahweh of the Bible, it should be apparent that they could not be referring to the same God. [http://www.clu.edu/allah-islam-same-yahweh-christianity]

ConclusionYes, pre-Islamic Arabic believers in Jesus used---and Believers in Muslim countries today still use---"Allah" to designate God, BUT with a non-Islamic connotation.
However, in free, informed, democratic countries in Western Civilization, Believers in Christ would not feel comfortable using "Allah" in their worship services! They are fully aware of the meaning given to it by Muhammad, which they would consider rank heresy...and blasphemy! The Name above all names of the invisible God, they avow, is Jehovah God (Yahweh), and His visible incarnation, Jesus! (Hebrews 1:1-14, 1 Timothy 1:17, Revelation 1:11-18)

@ james stuart - Yea, verily, the Jews do throw the SAME accusation at Christians.  As do the Muslims. There is no "danger" in recognizing this.  THE DANGER is in both Jew and Muslim---and every other religion---not believing the Prophets who said that invisible YAHWEH would  come to earth visibly (Isaiah 35), and pour out HIS Spirit on inhabitants of earth (Joel 2).  Humans did not make up the attributes (and essence) of God...they were revealed by God Himself.   As the Jewish prophets foretold, and as Qu'ran mentioned, Jesus was born of virgin....He was not just another man!  (Proverbs 30:4)
